# How to get these hints/guide in flutter UI development , any shortcuts

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, declarative

is there any shortcut for android studio for mac specially?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are autocomplete suggestions.

`ctrl+space` on mac works here as well.

You can also set the shortcut in your Android Studio preferences.

Also, check if Basic Completion is enabled.
Specifically: Prefs -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion -> Basic Completion

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks sahil sonwane sir, this made my flutter journey going good.